# Semantic Mediawiki query box

Tags: mediawiki

I am doing semantic searches via `Special:Ask`: `[[Has home::Barcelona]]`. However, I would like `Barcelona` to be an input variable by any user from a textbox. In other words, `Barcelona` might be `Madrid`, `Rome`, or `New York`. When clicking `Search`, it would appear the results.

I've found extensions like the extension `InputBox`, but it seems that it is not what I want. Do you have any idea how could I obtain this?

Comment: InputBox just enters parameters into other actions and special pages. You have to set up an inputbox which opens Special:Ask with the parameters you're looking for and the keyword entered by the user.

Comment: Correction, this seems unavailable with InputBox: I can only find types to use action=edit or Special:Search, not Special:Ask or other special pages. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InputBox Well, you could still make an inputbox-like form "manually".